# How to run initialization code before tests when using Python's unittest module as a testrunner?

Tags: python, unit-testing

How can a user of a library run his own initialization code (setting debug levels of loggers for example) before running tests supplied with the library? Python's `unittest` module is used as a testrunner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using pytest to run the unittests.  If that works (many unittest based test suites work), then you can create a little module, for example "mymod.py", defining a pytest configuration hook:

```
# content of mymod.py
def pytest_configure():
    import logging
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARN)
```

If you now execute py.test like this:

```
$ py.test -p mymmod --pyargs mylib
```

Then the "mylib" package will be searched for tests and ahead of running them the logging level is modified.  The "-p" option specifies a plugin to load and the "--pyargs" tells pytest to try importing the arguments first, instead of treating them as directory or file names (the default).

For more info: http://pytest.org and http://pytest.org/latest/unittest.html

HTH,
holger

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. This should be incorporated into `unittest` :)

Comment: Is there any way to execute your PYTHONSTARTUP file instead of `mymod` here ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the set-up work before calling *[unittest.main](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.main)*.

Or you could subclass the test suite and run a [class-level setup method](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass).

Or you could have the test setup incorporate a callback to a user-defined setup method.

Comment: ad 1. When running tests from command line user does not run `unittest.main` himself. ad 2. That's rather awkward if there are many test suits and one needs only to set loggers' debug levels. ad 3. This needs changes to the library's tests and I'm looking for a way to do it *externally*, without touching existing code.

Comment: ISTM you need to write a command-line wrapper for unittest.main() and apply one of the above listed techniques.  Unittest doesn't currently do what you want right out of the box.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost none that I'm aware of.  This is an actively maintained module, so you can always file a feature request at http://bugs.python.org

Answer (score 1):

Answer from similar question is more helpful here:

[How to a run a specific code before & after each unit test in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656864/how-to-a-run-a-specific-code-before-after-each-unit-test-in-python?rq=1)

I used python setUpClass method
https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass

```
setUpClass()
A class method called before tests in an individual class are run. setUpClass is called with the class as the only argument and must be decorated as a classmethod():

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    ...
```

I run my tests like this:

```
python -m unittest discover -v
```

Answer (score 0):

As I already had a conftest.py file in my pytest project, I added the initialization code to a method called `pytest_addoption`. The rest was history.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#initialization-hooks