# subclassing python unittest.Testcase, calling the same main

Tags: python, syntactic-sugar

I would like to create a subclass of python's unittest.Testcase called BasicTest. I would like each subclass of BasicTest to run the same routine in main. How can I accomplish this?

Example:

```
in basic_test.py:

class BasicTest(unittest.TestCase):

    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Do optparse stuff
    unittest.main()



in some_basic_test.py:

class SomeBasicTest(BasicTest):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #call the main in basic_test.py
```

Comment: Related: [How to run initialization code before tests when using Python's unittest module as a testrunner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607767/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# basic_test.py
class BasicTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @staticmethod
  def main():
     # Do optparse stuff
     unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  BasicTest.main()



# some_basic_test.py
class SomeBasicTest(BasicTest):
   ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  BasicTest.main()
```

Comment: What if there were more than one class inheriting from `BasicTest` in a test module? Initialization code (`BasicTest.main()`) will be run only once not before running methods from each test case.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (re)import a module as a new **main**, thus the `if __name__=="__main__"` code is kind of unreachable.

Dor’s suggestion or something similar seems most reasonable.
However if you have no access to the module in question, you might consider looking at the [runpy.run_module()](http://docs.python.org/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module) that executes a module as main.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like each subclass of BasicTest to run the same routine in main

I guess what you want is to run some setup/initialization code before running tests from any test case. In this case you might be interested in [`setUpClass`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures) class method.

testA.py

```
import unittest


class BasicTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print 'Preparing to run tests'


class TestA(BasicTest):

    def test1(self):
        print 'testA: test1'

    def test2(self):
        print 'testA: test2'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

testB.py

```
import unittest

from testA import BasicTest


class TestB(BasicTest):

    def test1(self):
        print 'testB: test1'

    def test2(self):
        print 'testB: test2'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output from testA.py:

```
Preparing to run tests
testA: test1
testA: test2
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Output from testB.py:

```
Preparing to run tests
testB: test1
testB: test2
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: I have to do some command line argument parsing before unittest.main() is called which is why I can't just use setUpClass