# How to a run specific code before & after each unit test in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

Following is the structure of my tests in a file.

Class 
 setup 
  test01 
  test02 
  test03 
 teardown

I have a requirement to run specific code before and after each test.

For before, I could invoke that code from the setup.
But for after the test, I am not able to figure how to do it.
Obviously invoking the code from teardown would work for the last test, but how can I have it run for the tests in between?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown there's also a setUp method to handle calling code before the test.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that you're properly using a class descended from `unittest.TestCase`, then the `setUp` method is run before each test, and the `tearDown` method is run after each test. [Check the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html). So it's completely feasible to put your code in those two methods.